# How to triggerShutdown a Guava AbstractScheduledService?

Tags: java, service, scheduled-tasks, guava

I'm using a few services inheriting from the `AbstractScheduledService`, which get managed by a `ServiceManager`. Everything works fine, but now, there's a service whose `runOneIteration` takes a rather long time, and as the result, my process takes too long to terminate (more than five seconds).

There are other services inheriting from `AbstractExecutionThreadService`, which had a similar problem, which I could solve via

```
@Override
protected final void triggerShutdown() {
    if (thread != null) thread.interrupt();
}
```

and storing `private volatile thread` in the `run` method. However, there's no `triggerShutdown` for `AbstractScheduledService` as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1918).

I already considered alternatives like making `runOneIteration` do less work, but it's both ugly and inefficient.

I can't override `stopAsync` as it's final and I can't see anything else. *Is there a hook for doing something like this?*

Comment: but you have shutDown() for AbstractScheduledService, there you can implement to update a flag and check this flag when running so you know when to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you work with this?  Was there any reason you couldn't add a triggerShutdown yourself?

```
class GuavaServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        GuavaServer gs = new GuavaServer();
        Set<ForceStoppableScheduledService> services = new HashSet<>();
        ForceStoppableScheduledService ts = gs.new ForceStoppableScheduledService();
        services.add(ts);
        ServiceManager manager = new ServiceManager(services);
        manager.addListener(new Listener() {
            public void stopped() {
                System.out.println("Stopped");
            }

            public void healthy() {
                System.out.println("Health");
            }

            public void failure(Service service) {
                System.out.println("Failure");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());

        manager.startAsync(); // start all the services asynchronously
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        manager.stopAsync();
        //maybe make a manager.StopNOW()?
        for (ForceStoppableScheduledService service : services) {
            service.triggerShutdown();
        }
    }

    public class ForceStoppableScheduledService extends AbstractScheduledService {

        Thread thread;

        @Override
        protected void runOneIteration() throws Exception {
            thread = Thread.currentThread();
            try {
                System.out.println("Working");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {// can your long process throw InterruptedException?
                System.out.println("Thread was interrupted, Failed to complete operation");
            } finally {
                thread = null;
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        }

        @Override
        protected Scheduler scheduler() {
            return Scheduler.newFixedRateSchedule(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        protected void triggerShutdown() {
            if (thread != null) thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Was there any reason you couldn't add a triggerShutdown yourself?"* I tried something similar, but it didn't work, most probably because of some stupid mistake. `+++` Anyway, the interrupt may hit a thread doing something else after `runOneIteration` finishes. This is solvable by nulling `thread` again, but it's getting more ugly (try-finally, and probably also synchronized). `+++` What I dislike most is the `manager` doing just half of its job (while it does everything for an `AbstractExecutionThreadService`).

Comment: you can always extend the ServiceManager and add a stopNow() but yeah the api doesn't seem to have support for it.  you can always try to put a pull request for it :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot about the bounty. It should be yours :(